# Minimize, shorten, optimize, simplify repetitive mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I am in need of a bit of help. I have to query my database for each and every ID I have in one of the tables to get specific data for that ID.

My query looks like this:
`SELECT fb_id, user_name FROM user WHERE user_id = X`

I have thousands of user IDs I have to run this query for and I don't like the idea of running thousands of queries on every page load. This is a search page so it is heavily used.

Is there any possibility this could be optimised?

Comment: "I don't like the idea of running thousands of queries on every page load" why do you need to this now?

Comment: You've said this is a search page, so why not `JOIN` the data instead of querying for each result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are truly running this same simple query for different values of `user_id`, why bother with the `WHERE` clause? Just select all rows (or whatever subset you need) with their `user_id`  and fetch them into an array in your application code.

```
SELECT user_id, fb_id, user_name FROM user
```

Answer (score 1):

My bet

```
SELECT fb_id, user_name FROM one_of_my_tables o LEFT JOIN user u ON o.uid=u.id
```

I see no point in running even this one on every page load.

Answer (score 0):

1. put a key on "user_id"
2. add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query (this is unique, right?)

Comment: To add... with some more info about when and why you call the query, maybe we can lessen the calls all together.